# Chronometer: I want to make a button reset to "00.00" not restart the chronometer

Tags: android, timer, reset, chronometer

I want the start button to start the time, the stop button to completely stop it at that time, and the reset button to start the clock back at "00.00". Everytime I click reset it restarts the time. I just want it to reset back to "00.00". Thanks for your help. Heres my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class TimeLogActivity extends ActionBarActivity {Chronometer focus;
Button start, stop, reset;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_log);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeLogStartButton);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeLogStopButton);
    reset  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeLogResetButton);

    focus = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.timeLogChronometer);


    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            focus.start();
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            focus.stop();
        }
    });

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            focus.start();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_time_log, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that you have focus.start() inside your reset button's OnClickListener?

Comment: I was playing around with it. This is my new code that I was playing around with. It initially had focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()); and didn't work

Answer (score 10):

These lines you should be able to reset the chronometer back to 00:00

```
focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
focus.stop();
```

Answer (score 6):

reset the focus and start counting

```
focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
```

then you can just say

```
focus.stop();
```

That's how I would reset and stop the focus at 00:00.

Idk any better way atm.

Answer (score 2):

If you call these two lines one after the other you will be done

```
focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
focus.stop();
```

What it does is, start the chronometer again and quickly stop it.
This worked for me and seems to be the best solution currently.

Answer (score 0):

```
focus.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
```

SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() != 00:00

Comment: I tried to use this code with the !=00:00 and its not working right